# Adding a FloatingActionButton as a FooterView to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I want to add a FloatingActionButton beneath a ListView (so that the button is always the last item of the ListView).
I found a method, which can do this called addFooterView.
When i try to add the FAB though, i get an error:

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

It seems like the Params of my FAB cant be casted to the RelativeLayout Parameters. 
How can I solve this Problem? Or is there another way to achieve this effect?

My (relevant) XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_below="@id/container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

(relevant) part of my Code:

```
ListView container = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.container);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

container.addFooterView(fab);
```

Comment: FAB is used to showcase always at the right bottom of the screen. Most libraries does it automatical placement. May I ask why again do you need to realign to the last item of ListView?

Comment: zIronManBox He want to save the space until the last item is displayed i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT add a view as a footer view which already has a parent.
You should create the `FloatingActionButton` in code, and then add it as a footer view.

But as others said, UX-wise it is way better to show it on top of the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it on the `CoordinatorLayout` which that has this effect.

Since you are using `AppbarLayout` that is simply to use with `CoordinatorLayout`:

**Implementation:**

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppbarLayout/>
    <scrollableView/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Example:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />
```

**This is the standard way from (`MaterialDesign`) to doing that.**

Also, you can check this out: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/